# Sync Services error on Windows 7 when iPhone 4S is plugged in

Tags: data-synchronization, windows, iphone, itunes

I am currently running iTunes 10.5.1 on a Windows 7 Home PC and when I plug my iPhone 4S into my computer via the USB cable it freezes. iTunes in Task Manager shows up as not responding and after a few minutes it displays the following error:

> iTunes was unable to load data class information from Sync Services.
>   Reconnect or try again later.

What causes this issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled your error message and I found [this page](http://leimobile.com/fix-itunes-was-unable-to-load-provider-data-from-sync-services-reconnect-or-try-again-later/) and [this apple support thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1595916?start=0&tstart=0).

Hope this helps !

Edit:  Solution #2 in the Lei Mobile site seemed to resolve my issue.  I renamed the C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\AppleComputer\SyncSerivces to SyncServices_old.  I was at least able to plug in my iPhone and perform an initial back up.

I will continue to use to see if that is the permanent fix.